# Neural networks for a 3d space value linked list matching in java

Tags: java, algorithm, pattern-matching, neural-network

I am trying to match a prerecorded 3d(float x, float y, float z) linked list to another 3d linked list(float x, float y, float z). There is about 50 prerecorded sequences with 1000 examples of the same move every time, against which I am trying to match through. 
The size of linked lists highly vary.
Is there a specific neural network pattern/library/framework/algorhytm in Java I could use for this task ?

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!
Waiting for your replies)

Comment: Have you tried hasing functions? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function

Comment: have you tried a simple loop?

Comment: simple loop won't be a solution as values might be too different e.g. someone is bigger and someone is smaller, hash function wouldn't be a perfect solution aswell as I am looking for the way to do it with neural network..

Comment: What purpose does the neural network serve here? I think this is a good task for Dynamic time warping (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping), but very bad for neural networks. Please expand some more details.

Comment: Dear LiKao I have already implemented the DTW and FastDTW and accessed their performance, I was told I need to move to Neural Networks. I have data extracted from sensor Kinect parsed and saved in the linkedlist of Point3D, I am trying to find sequences from data I get get recorded on the fly and data I have previously recorded. I am trying to find matches e.g. classify the sequence with one of the pre recorded moves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on a neural network...

**Simplify your prerecorded input**

- For each 3d point list create 3 black and white 2d images of your points (drawing a line between each adjacent point)
- Top-down (x,z)
- Forward-back (x,y)
- Left-right (z,y)

**Simplify your user input**

- Create the same 3 black and white images (explained above)
- Find the bounding box of the points and scale the image to a uniform size
- - Having your user input, scaled to same size as your prerecorded input will facilitate recognition

**Create neural networks for image recognition**

- Create a trained network for your prerecorded (3 images for each)
- This seems like it would work http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/image_recognition.html
- Build your neural nets from the black and white images (that represent the 2d mapping of your 3d points onto the 3 perpendicular planes)

**Experiment with your matching bounds/constraints**

- IF Top2Bottom >= 0.75 AND Forward2Back >= 0.75 AND Left2Right >= 0.75
- THEN IsAMatch = True
- ELSE IsAMatch = False

---

I would probably just generate a large 3d corridor (think wide 3d tube, or a collection of connected cylinders) that represented the extremes of my prerecorded points then scale the user input points then check if the user input points fall within the matching corridor.

---

**EDIT** Very odd that the question itself was down-voted and closed, then days later my answer was down-voted. Realistically, the question was likely closed due to a failure of group think on the part of the moderators. Maybe it then looked a little awkward to have a closed question with a +1 "Accepted" answer, so this answer was subsequently down-voted (twice).

From my experience, the only way to ask a question like this is to either slap a large bounty on it, or re-word it in a way that won't offend the fragile sensibilities of the moderators (most of the time they do a good job and don't overstep...).

Comment: for the explanation with 3 images template matching algorithm would @LastCoder the idea with 3 images looks great will implement it as well, however I am thinking of using the Encog not the neuroph as it allows image analysis on the fly. Could you please tell me more about the 3D corridor idea ? Akonkagva

Comment: @user1165088 - consider a 3d tunnel/tube, it would be a collection of (Vector3, Radius) pairs. Now you have a user generated list of 3d points you stretch/scale those points to fit the bounds of your 3d tunnel then you see if those points lie within the tunnel or not using the distance formula.

Comment: thank you for great ideas, I will implement them both !